# What do I use for host: in a postgres database when postgres is installed in a google instance?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have a google cloud intance and in that instance i have installed docker and postgres.Then I pull an image of a node/express server from Docker Hub and dockerized that image.My goal is to make them talk to each other. I'm having a hard time trying to communicate with one another).
This is how i have my dockerize server is talking to my database:
if i was running this on my local machine i would use host:localhost
I'm not sure what to use for host in a VM ?

```js
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "postgres",
  password: "somepassowed",
  host: '',
  port: 5432,
  database: "postgres"
})

module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "installing postgres"?

Comment: meaning that once i created my compute instance open up the shell and installed postgres with this command sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib and installed docker as well to containerize my server image

Comment: If PostreSQL is running within the OS and your application is running inside the container, you need to use `host.docker.internal`, the host operating systems IP address, or `localhost`. This depends on how you setup Docker networking. It is easy to just try each method. The first method depends on the Host OS and Docker version. If PostgresQL is only listening on `localhost` you might have to change `postgresql.conf` to listen on all interfaces `listen_addresses = '*'`. The best answer depends on configuration details for the OS, Docker and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot and gives me a better understanding!

Comment: If the solution is working could you please leave it as an Answer instead of a comment?